# Different colors in different devices android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed an app for android. For this i have used a green color for the actionbar. I have applied the color from where I designed the screens. But colors look different on different devices. How can I say this devices is corrent?

Comment: Color looks different because of device densities

Comment: So, whichone we should prefer i mean which density

Comment: give values for color instead Color.GREEN or something

Comment: We can not determine density. It decide by manufacturer of device when they made it. You will feel a little difference. And i suggest, leave it like that

Answer (score 2):

The color can vary according to the display type of phone,For example the Galaxy S3 has a Super AMOLED Display which gives more fluorescent colors.The organic materials used in AMOLED displays are prone to degradation over a period of time, resulting in color shifts as one color fades faster than another, image persistence or burn-in.LED-backlit LCD,gives more realistic color but the  brightness may be less.

In common you can assign a color to your action bar and see the color in different devices and  pick a color which displays good on all.

Answer (score 0):

> How to solve this problem?

You cannot, because it's most likely not your fault. It's just different hardware. You cannot do much about this.

> Please suggest me a solution.

Just ignore this.